# In an equilateral triangle, prove that $|BQ| + |PQ| + |CP| > 2l$

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle with side $l$.
>
> If $P$ and $Q$ are points respectively in sides $AB$ and $AC$, different from the triangle vertices, prove that $$|BQ| + |PQ| + |CP| > 2l$$

I can see that, as point $P$ tends to $A$, $|CP|+|PQ|$ tends to $|AC|+|AQ|$. If I could prove this, the problem would be solved (the rest follows from the triangle inequality).

However I have no clue on how to do this. I tried to play with triangle inequality and relations between sides and angles but nothing worked.

How can I proceed?

Comment: I think you have made a typo in your question - let $Q$ approach $B$ and $P$ approach $C$. Then the limit of $BQ$ and $CP$ is 0, and the limit of $PQ$ is $l$ (draw it out!). Therefore I think the inequality should be $|BQ| + |PQ| + |CP| > l$.

Comment: That's true, but if you let $Q$ and $P$ approach $A$, the sum approaches $|AB|+|AC|$.

Comment: But that is the more inefficient case - the case should hold for any $P$ and $Q$, not just one example that you have described.

Comment: Now I realized you might have mislabeled your sketch; actually $Q$ approaches $C$, not $B$, and the inverse for $P$.

Comment: If $P$ and $Q$ are the midpoints then the statement is trivial. If either $P$ or $Q$ are far from $A$ (by far I mean farther than midway) the result follows by the first case. So you are left only with the case when both $P$ and $Q$ are close to $A$.

Comment: Missed the word "respectively" - I thought that $P$ was on $AC$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Upon reflection ...

[image]

$$2s = |\overline{AB^\prime}| \leq |\overline{AP}|+|\overline{PQ^\prime}|+|\overline{Q^\prime B^\prime}| = p+q+r$$

Comment: It was something amazing!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Fantastic

Answer (score 2):

Let $AQ=x$, $AP=y$ and $l=1$.

Thus, $$PQ=\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2},$$
$$PC=\sqrt{y^2-y+1}$$ and
$$BQ=\sqrt{x^2-x+1}$$ and we need to prove that
$$\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2-x+1}+\sqrt{y^2-y+1}\geq2.$$
Now, by Minkowwski
$$\sqrt{x^2-x+1}+\sqrt{y^2-y+1}=\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}+\sqrt{\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}+y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)^2}=\sqrt{(x+y-1)^2+3}$$ and
$$\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}\geq\frac{x+y}{2}.$$
Let $x+y=2a$.

Hence, $a\leq1$ and we need to prove that
$$a+\sqrt{(2a-1)^2+3}\geq2$$ or
$$\sqrt{4a^2-4a+4}\geq2-a$$ or
$$4a^2-4a+4\geq a^2-4a+4,$$
which is obvious.

Done!

By my solution easy to make a geometric proof.

Comment: Quite an interesting approach! I was looking for a more geometric argument, but thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, rather it is a suggested approach to the problem. Here is a Geogebra ([link](https://ggbm.at/mmxdSjhF))diagram:

If you go to the Geogebra link you can move points $P$ and $Q$.

The problem is reduced to proving that $|DI|>|IQ|$.

[image: Geometric Diagram]

Note from the construction that $|PQ|=|DQ|$ and $|CP|=|BG|=|BF|$ and that $2l=|IH|$.

Therefore

$$ |PQ|+|BQ|+|CP|=|DQ|+|QB|+|BF|=|DF| $$

So to establish the result it must be shown that

$$ |DI|>|FH|=|IQ| $$

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the graph (using smartphone, will draw at PC later) below:

[image]